# Getting error Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to generate random numbers between 0 and 1, and push them to two dimension array. And i'm getting this error:

> Cannot use a scalar value as an array

This is my code:

```
<?php 

    $zero = $one = $rand = 0;
    $arr = array(array());

    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $arr[$i] = $rand;

        for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
            $rand = mt_rand(0,1);
            if ($rand == 0) {
                $one++;
            } else {
                $zero++;
            }
            $arr[$i][$j] = $rand;
            echo $arr[$i][$j];
        }
            echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well here: `$arr[$i] = $rand;`, if we take the first iteration, you do: `$arr[0] = 0;` and then in the second for loop you try to use the value `0` as an array and store something in it, which of course won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$arr[$i]` is a scalar value as you are assigning it an integer here:

```
$arr[$i] = $rand;
```

There for it is *not* an array. But you are trying to access it like an array which throws this error:

```
$arr[$i][$j] = $rand;
```

You either need to make that value an array or use a different variable for holding your array data. But you can't do both at once.

Comment: Thank's for explaining!